# How to pass multiple variables from view to controller in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I want to pass form data from the view to the function inside a controller. What are the ways to do it?

Comment: href="{{ route('getentry', [$entry->filename]) }}"

but i cant get it to work for multiple variables

Comment: possible duplicate of [Submit Multiple Select Values to an Action in Laravel 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596679/submit-multiple-select-values-to-an-action-in-laravel-4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply this:

In **View**:

```
{ Form::open(array('action' => 'Controller@method')) }}
    {{ Form::text('rate', '', array('placeholder' => 'Enter new custom client rate...')) }}
    {{ Form::submit('Submit', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

In your **Controller:**

```
class Controller extends BaseController {
   public function method()
   {
       // get the rate value
       $rate = Input::get('rate');

       or

       // to get all form values
       $allFormValues = Input::all();

   }
}
```

And that's it.

Laravel is smart enough to get all of those request values.